# Why would you not import java.util when declaring arraylists in a class

Tags: java

I've been reviewing some code and I found the following for a field:

```
private List<String> listOfStrings = java.util.ArrayList<String>();
```

When would it be preferable to use this code as opposed to:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

...

private List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Is there any benefit, apart from the difference in syntax?

Answer (score 5):

The only other possible benefit would be in a situation where another class called `ArrayList` exists. For instance:

```
package foo.bar;

class ArrayList { /* ... */ }
```

Then, if you wanted to use *both* this and the `java.util` class in the same file, you'd need to use the fully qualified name of one or both classes.

Comment: True. Although anyone willingly creating a class called `ArrayList` in anything but a sandbox should suffer a horrible punishment.